# Error when assigning data to new column in ShinyApp datatable: replacement has 0 rows

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, datatable, shinyapps

Everything works until I try to assign pmin to a new column; at which point I get the error "replacement has 0 rows, data has 70." If I take out the line where I marked "#here", I would get two tabs of interactive ShinyApp tables. What do I do? Is this a ShinyApp problem or dataframe or did I do anything that I should not have done?

edit: turns out it's my fault for naming one of the input$ variables wrong in one of the lines and so that was the reason for the code to not work.

Comment: Can you show the data as well i.e. few lines of `berlin_table` or `china_table`

Comment: Edited to add the relevant bit... hope this is useful! Thanks for dropping by anyway.

Comment: Probably use `na.rm = TRUE` as it is still not clear i.e. `pmin(china_table$lim,input$a_c, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Didn't work :/ still says replacement has 0 rows, data has 70, and tbh I want to keep the NAs so that the output would include the NAs still

Comment: Can you add `dput` of head of your data in case if it is showing the same error.  Then, it could be a reproducible example

Comment: done! hope this helps

Comment: Is the dput based on `china_table` or `berlin_table`

Comment: its based on china_table and china_table only

Comment: Lol so it turns out one of my variables input$a_c was input$a_C... sorry for wasting your (and 2 hours of my) time man ;_;

Comment: Initially, I had the same doubt but I didn't notice the uppercase

Comment: I've spent more than three days finding out that it was also my issue.
LESSON: When you are told that your replacement has 0 rows, it could be that you misspelled something.